# Cannot trim from the end of string

Tags: c#, string, trim

When the following is executed:

```
foreach (String fromList in columns)
{
    query += "`" + fromList + "`,";
}
query.TrimEnd(',');
```

The comma is not trimmed from the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Building a query with concatenation.  Occasionally necessary, usually wrong.

Comment: Of course, the general way to approach this problem would be to use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) which inserts separator characters between each string to be joined together. Slightly more complex here to first wrap each string with `` characters, but still usually a better option than building a complete string, then re-modifying it to remove characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TrimEnd` returns the new string. You need:

```
query = query.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: That worked thank you.  I wonder why no errors were indicated by Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @user1600684 because your call to `TrimEnd` was valid. Whether you do something with the result or not is not something that VS would generally not warn you about.

Comment: Why would you expect an error?  There is nothing syntactically incorrect with your code.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, so you need to store the return value from TrimEnd.

```
query = query.TrimEnd(',');
```

Though there is an easier way to do this:

```
var query = String.Join(",", columns.Select(fromList => String.Format("`{0}`", fromList)));
```

Comment: Just a note, needed a .ToArray() on the lambda in .net 3.5

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that. Only .NET 4 and newer have a String.Join that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` directly.

Answer (score 1):

TrumEnd returns a string. Are you assigning it to a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. If you want the result after applying `TrimEnd`, you have to assign that result to a variable:

```
foreach (String fromList in columns)
{
    query += "`" + fromList + "`,";
}
query = query.TrimEnd(',');
```

Here I've assigned it back to itself.

---

Of course, better would be something like:

```
query = String.Join(",",fromList.Select(a=>"`" + a + "`"));
```

instead of the loop + edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below example:

```
var trimmed = query.TrimEnd(',');
Console.WriteLine(trimmed);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
foreach (String fromList in columns)
{
    query += "`" + fromList + "`,";
}
query = query.TrimEnd(',');
```